# iOS App "No longer available" on old iOS after bumping deployment target

Tags: ios, app-store

we have a fairly old app that until very recently had iOS 9.3 as minimum deployment target.

After increasing the deployment target to iOS 11, I can no longer open the App on my iPad 2 with iOS 9.3 with an Alert ""App" Is No Lonager Available". (A previous version of the app is installed on my iPad, this old version of the App does now not launch anymore).

And I can not download the App from the AppStore on iOS 9.3 with an alert "Unable to Purchase - "App" is not compatible with this iPad." - this is with an Account with which I had installed the App before.

I thought it was supposed to work the way that, when updating the deployment target, users on older OSs can still use and download the last compatible version of the app?

In the AppStore under "Pricing and Availability" -> "Last-Compatible Version Settings", All Versions are checked (Version 4.41.0 is the first one without iOS9 support).

[image: AppStore Availability Settings]

[image: AppStore Availability Settings - All Versions selected]

Is there something we have missed?

Comment: I am the developer of this app and I want our users on old devices to still be able to use the app. Yes, the iPad did check the AppStore if the version is still available before refusing to launch the installed version of the app. We are getting support emails from users on old iOS versions who can not use the app anymore, thats why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Of course iOS checks if an installed app is available for sale, there's nothing magical about it. The AppStore explicitly supports revoking access to older versions, how else would this work? The issue is - my old app version is not available even though all older versions are selected to be available in the AppStore

Comment: Well this would be a question for Apple. I don't see what you want _us_ to do about it. It's not a programming matter.

Comment: Yeah, I have already posted in the Apple Developer Forums and contacted Apple Support, but after some days without reply I thought I would also try SO. Im not expecting YOU to do anything about it, but maybe there is something we've missed, like "Oh, you have to set this and that setting in the Xcode Project and watch for Y option during upload to make it actually work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found that there is a way for users to still install the App.

When going to App's site in the AppStore and trying to install, you get the aforementioned error

> Unable to Purchase - "App" is not compatible with this iPad.

But if you go to the "Purchases" tab in the Store, search for the app and re-download from there, you get another dialog with the option to install the last compatible version - as expected.

I still don't understand why you can not launch the still installed old version of the app anymore, you will have to re-install via your "Purchases" tab.